# Jquery - .post - .load animations?

Tags: jquery

I'm having trouble getting animations to work after .load in a queue.  I'm not too familiar with the .queue function, but in this case, the .post writes to a page and I have to wait a bit for it to update the mysql database, hence the .delay and the .queue for the .load. The #current_question div lies within the it.jsp page, which seems to be causing all the problems. Maybe I'm doing it all wrong, regardless the #current_questions animations do not load.

Please help a hack get it working properly!  Thanks.

```
$.post("it.jsp",
        {
            fail: "1"
        }
);
$('#current_question').fadeOut(300);
$('#it_refresh').delay(500).queue(function(next) {
    $('#it_refresh').on().load('it.jsp');
    next();
    $('#current_question').hide();
    $('#current_question').fadeIn(1000);
});
```

Comment: You're invoking `on()` without arguments before chaining into `load()`, which might fail and break the chain. Also, calling `next()` should be the last thing you do from the queued function, sticking it in the middle of the code will probably don't work as intended.

Answer (score 0):

If you post something to a script, i guess that script will write to the database? If so: why not just return the new HTML and wait for the `.post` callback?

```
(function(){
    var $currentQuestion = $('#current_question'),
        $itRefresh = $('#it_refresh');
    $currentQuestion.fadeOut(300);
    $.post('it.jsp',{fail: "1"}, function(response) {
        $itRefresh.html(response);
        $currentQuestion.fadeIn(1000);
    });
})();
```

I added an IIFE to provide a scope to not interfere with your currently existing variables.

Comment: This does not work because the #current_question div lies within the it.jsp page.  Jquery doens't see it without .on, correct?